# create loop to switch from one socket to another

Tags: python, sockets, beagleboneblack

So I have successfully created a socket connection to one client and another, but I am having trouble getting them to switch from one another with loops, did some while true and if statements to make the program recognize when one system wants to switch based on user input but I don't think I'm doing it right. Can some one help me out with a code to switch back and forth

The following is the code I'm attempting to implement.

This is the code on my computer:

```
import socket,sys,os,time
T2='yourturn'

serverAddr = ('192.168.0.120', 20104)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    #client.connect(serverAddr)
sock = client
client.connect(('192.168.0.120', 20104))
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
def redirectOut(port=20104, host='192.168.0.11'):
        """
        connect caller's standard output stream to a socket for GUI to listen
        start caller after listener started, else connect fails before accept
        """
        
        sock = client
                        # caller operates in client mode
        file = sock.makefile('w')                 # file interface: text, buffered
        sys.stdout = file 
                    # make prints go to sock.send
        return sock
        


########################################33333

time.sleep(10)

HOST = ''
PORT2 = 20105


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created')

try:
        l=s.bind((HOST, PORT2))
except socket.error as msg:
        print('Bind failed. ')
        sys.exit()

print('Socket bind complete')


s.listen(10)
print('Socket now listening')

conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connected to ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))






####################################################

time.sleep(10)





while True:
    if T2!='yourturn':
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        line = data.decode    # convert to string (Python 3 only)
        T2=print(line)
    else :
        if T2=='myturn':
            break
        else:
            redirectOut()
            T2=print(input())
```

this is the code on my begalbone black:

```
import socket
import sys
import os, time



HOST = ''
PORT2 = 20104
T='yourturn'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created')

try:
        l=s.bind((HOST, PORT2))
except socket.error as msg:
        print('Bind failed. ')
        sys.exit()
        


print('Socket bind complete')


s.listen(10)
print('Socket now listening')

conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connected to ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))


#################################################################
time.sleep(15)
serverAddr = ('192.168.0.11', 20105)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock = client

try:
  sock.connect(('192.168.0.11', 20105))
  fsr = 'P9_40'
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except TimeoutError:
  os.system('reboot')


def redirectOut(port=20105, host='192.168.0.120'):
    """
    connect caller's standard output stream to a socket for GUI to listen
    start caller after listener started, else connect fails before accept
    """
    sock = client
                    # caller operates in client mode
    file = sock.makefile('w')                 # file interface: text, buffered
    sys.stdout = file                         # make prints go to sock.send
    return sock 




##############################################################

time.sleep(10)



while True:
    
      if T!='myturn':
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        line = data.decode('UTF-8')    # convert to string (Python 3 only)
        T=print(line)
      else:
        redirectOut()
        if T=='yourturn':
            break
        else:
            T=print(input())
```

So tried this while loop: but its still hanging up, I think I'm close:

```
T2='yourturn'
while True:
 #for line in 'Python':
    print(T2)
    time.sleep(10)
    if T2=='myturn':
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        line = data.decode 
        print("myturn print")
        l=print(line)
        if l=="yourturn":
            continue
    if T2=="yourturn" or T2!='myturn':
        print(T2)
        print('myturn send')
        redirectOut()# convert to string (Python 3 only)
        k=input()
        if k=="myturn":
            T2='myturn'
            continue
```

Tried the folowing but reciving machine is hanging up when myturn is input:

sending:

```
time.sleep(3)
T2='yourturn'
print('here')
while True:
 #for line in 'Python':
    #print(T2)
    #time.sleep(10)
    if T2=='myturn':
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        line = data.decode('UTF-8')
        #print("myturn print")
        l=print(line)
        if l=="yourturn":
            T2='yourturn'
            continue
    if T2=="yourturn" and T2!='myturn':
        #print(T2)
        #print('myturn send')
        redirectOut()# convert to string (Python 3 only)
        k=input()
        print(k)
    if k=="myturn":
        T2=print('myturn')
        T2='myturn'
        print('there')
        continue
```

receiving:

```
time.sleep(3)
T='yourturn'
while True:
 #for line in 'Python':
    #print(T)

    if T=='yourturn':
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        line = data.decode('UTF-8')
        #print("myturn print")
        l=print(line)
        if l=='myturn':
          T='myturn'
          continue
        if l=='exit':
          client.close()
          break
    if T=='myturn' and T!='yourturn':
        #print('myturn send')
        redirectOut()# convert to string (Python 3 only)
        k=input()
        print(k)
        if k=='yourturn':
          T=print('yourturn')
          continue
```

Comment: standard method: server has to run every connection in separated thread - and main thread may still run `accept` to get connection from next client.

Comment: I don't understand your `if/else` with `T2` - there is too many combinations and it can block code. Server may wait for data from client but at the same time client can wait for data from server.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: I started doing print statements last night to figure out what was hanging things up, I did a print statement on k and found that its posting as none to the reviving machine, as such the sending machine never switches to receive i think. if i print k after input the receiving machine does not switch to sending. editing my code up top to reflect my new dumb loop.  the treading solution would be nice to learn i guess, but i would hate to bash my head around other solutions unless some one has a solid example for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I recommend Beej's guide to network programming". https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ Reading this will address 90% of all the questions you are likely to encounter. Even though it isn't python specific all network code is largely the same.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, removed my reditectOut function and opened the port with windows firewall to implement this code:

My computer:

```
T2='yourturn'
while True:
    if T2=='myturn':
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        line = data.decode('UTF-8')
        print(line)
        l=line
        if l=="yourturn":
            T2='yourturn'
            continue
    if T2=="yourturn" and T2!='myturn':
        k=input()
        client.sendto(k.encode('utf-8'),('192.168.0.120', 20104))
    if k=="myturn":
        T2='myturn'
        continue
```

Beagle bone black:

```
time.sleep(3)
T='yourturn'
while True:
    if T=='yourturn':
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        line = data.decode('UTF-8')
        print(line)
        l=line
        if l=='myturn':
          T='myturn'
          continue
    if T=='myturn' and T!='yourturn':
        k=input()
        client.sendto(k.encode('utf-8'),('192.168.0.11', 20105))
        if k=='yourturn':
          T='yourturn'
          continue
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73438279/5) to the question [create loop to switch from one socket to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73438279/create-loop-to-switch-from-one-socket-to-another) by the OP [Munix0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19739343/munix0) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>